# Youtube url not working with android webview

Tags: android, html, webview

In my hybrid basis android application, When i load the following embed code in webview,audio only coming and the screen shows blank screen,Here the html code,

```
<tr>
 <td width="20%" class="dr"><strong>Wk 0 Tues</strong></td>
 <td width="40%">Three surprising reasons to pray</td>
 <td width="20%" > <a href="#this-video-1" id="video1" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window"  data-transition="pop" style="color:#fff" >VIDEO</a></td>
</tr>
<div data-role="popup" id="this-video-1" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="c" data-dismissible="false" class="ui-content">
<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="f" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right" id='close1'>Close</a>
<div id="video-holder">
<object id="raj" width="100%"  height="250" type="text/html" data="http://www.youtube.com/embed/2qzxf0B0byA">Unable to play video. Please check your internet connection. 
</object>
</div>
</div>
```

What change requires to show the audio and video together.

Answer (score 0):

Call WebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); on your WebView instance.

Comment: i did ..But still only audio is vaialable not video

Comment: Have you tried to load the same HTML from the Chrom browser application?

Comment: webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true) ?